# Ошибка при поиске значения в БД MySQL

Tags: php, pdo

Пишу функцию поиска значения в таблице, но выскакивает ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password = 'HERES MY PASSWORD' ' at line 1' in W:\domains\blog\components\Database.php:47 Stack trace: #0 W:\domains\blog\components\Database.php(47): PDOStatement->execute() #1 W:\domains\blog\models\Auth.php(28): Database->find('users', Array) #2 W:\domains\blog\controllers\AuthController.php(48): Auth::login(Array) #3 [internal function]: AuthController->actionLogin() #4 W:\domains\blog\components\Router.php(42): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 W:\domains\blog\index.php(13): Router->run() #6 {main} thrown in W:\domains\blog\components\Database.php on line 47

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct($DB_HOST, $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) 
    {
        parent::__construct("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
        parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }   

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function find($table, $data, $where = NULL)
    {
        if ($where == NULL) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $where .= "$key = :$key,";
            }

            $where = rtrim($where, ',');
        }

        $sql = $this->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where LIMIT 1");

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $sql->bindValue(":$key", $value);
        }

        $sql->execute();

        if ($sql->fetch())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

В итоге получается такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = :username,`password` = :password LIMIT 1
```

Ошибка вылезает только тогда, когда в параметр `$data` поступает `count($data) > 1` значений. Исходя из этого, можно подумать, что проблема в самом начале функции - тело цикла `foreach()`, но не понимаю, что не так.

Comment: Так может вместо запятой правильнее ставить `AND` в условии? Это был риторический вопрос.

Comment: @Visman почему же `AND`? Обычно запятую всегда писал. А если случай, когда поиск не по двум значениям (username, password), а по нескольким? после каждого значения `AND` писать?

Comment: Если вы ищите запись по нескольким полям, так чтобы каждое поле записи удовлетворяло определенному условию тогда используем логическое И между условиями. Если ищите запись с хотя бы одним совпадением по всем условиям - используете логическое ИЛИ. В более сложных случаях придется использовать комбинацию логических операторов (операторов сравнения, круглых скобок, функций).

Comment: @phen0men поставьте вместо запятой - `AND` и запрос сработает. Никогда такого не было, чтобы в MySQL вместо `AND` можно быть запятую использовать

Comment: Всякий раз, когда пытаешься выпендриться пооригинальнее, следует помнить об опасности SQL инъекций

Comment: @Ипатьев в чем заключается опасность в моем коде?

Comment: @Visman проблему решил, большое спасибо.

Comment: В том, в чем и всегда - неконтролируемых данных в запросе. Рекомендую поскорее вырсти и перестаь писать функции типа find(), вся польза от которых - написать за тебя целых ЧЕТЫРЕ слова, а вреда - ведром черпать заколебешься.

Comment: @Ипатьев а что, если эта функция используется при авторизации пользователя, к примеру, либо же при регистрации, когда нужно определить, существует ли какой-либо логин\почта в таблице? к тому же, данные можно отфильтровать - массив `$data`, а только потом вызывать `find($table, $data)`

Comment: Вот именно что "можно". Вот на этом невысказанном предположении и держится, перефразируя Пелевина, весь хрупкий механизм сетевой безопасности. Вырастай уже быстрее и переставай считать себя умнее других. Безопасно только то, что безопасно безо всяких "можно". плюс ты экономишь совсем не там где надо. Поверь, написать $db->run("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username=?", [$username])->fetch() не так тяжело, как тебе кажется. Но зато через месяц читая свой код, ты без проблем поймешь, что он делает. В отличие от $db->find("users", ["username" => $username])

Comment: @Ипатьев хорошо, переписываю функцию, большое спасибо. Вопрос - как вы обернули запрос и вывод в два вызова? `$db->run($query, $data)->fetch()`. Вот, что я написал, но выводит ошибку (ошибку тоже написал): https://pastebin.com/U2wLjcnD

Comment: run() - это функция выполнкения запроса, она должна быть в db(). Например вот такая, https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#run

Comment: @Ипатьев надо было возвращать `$sql`, а я возвращал `$sql->execute(...)`.  Все, разобрался, большое спасибо. А что вы скажете насчет **[этого?](https://pastebin.com/jvcDu2GK)** Тоже не безопасно?

Comment: Я просто покажу пример инъекции: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае вместо запятой в **WHERE** нужно поставить оператор **AND**